# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException in Entity Framework (Web API)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, dapper

My web controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Description;
using Account;

namespace Account.Controllers
{
    public class ORDER_DETAILController : ApiController
    {
        private restaurantEntities db = new restaurantEntities();

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/ORDER_DETAIL/PendingOrders/{id}")]
        [ResponseType(typeof(ORDER_DETAIL))]
        public IQueryable<Orders> PendingOrders(int id)
        {
            Class1 obj = new Class1();
            return obj.GetOrders(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Data.SqlClient;
 using Dapper;

 namespace AccountStoredProc.Controllers
 {
     public class Class1
     {
         public IQueryable<Orders> GetOrders(int id)
         {
             using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("integrated security = true ; data source = RAHUL - PAVILION;")) 
             {
                 conn.open();
                 return conn.Query<Orders>($"select * from ORDER_DETAIL WHERE VEN_ID={id} and ORD_STATUS='PENDING' ").AsQueryable();
             }    
          }
      }
 }
```

When I hit the below URL:

```
https://localhost:44331/api/ORDER_DETAIL/PendingOrders/1
```

I get this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)
>
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

I know I already opened the connection while creating EF but how can I execute my query in `GetOrders()` without a `SqlConnection` variable called `conn` I am not able to execute my query without `conn` variable?

NOTE: connection establishment is working in normal console application and other predefined methods like get, search in account controller but in my predefined method it is not working.

Comment: I doubt that your machine name is: "RAHUL - PAVILION" !?

Comment: @ErikEJ Agreed. That connection string would definitely cause that error.

Comment: You have an SQL injection issue: you are concatenating `id` into the query, you should be using SQL parameter, like so `@id`

Answer (score 1):

Please check your connection string, especially on spaces

example format for connectiong string:

```
 `connetionString = @"Data Source=WIN-50GP30FGO75; integrated security = true; Initial Catalog=Demodb;User ID=sa;Password=demol23";`
```

Comment: You cannot mix integrated security and username / password

Comment: @ErikEJ Just showing the format, even though you can mix them If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will be used.